# Need help will collapsable menu using JQuery resize function

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, frontend

At less than 850px wide, a button is present that when clicked shows a menu. I would like it so that past 850px the button disappears and menu display is switched. This part is working, but I would also like it that when the window goes past 850px and back to below 850px the menu is hidden regardless if the button was clicked or not. This is all working.

Only problem is that now the way I have it set up if the the button is pressed and a resize event occurs, the menu is collapsed again. I would like the menu to remain if window is less than 850px wide.

Not quite sure what I can do with the code to make both these events happen.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.navbar-toggle').click(function() {
        $('.navbar-collapse').toggleClass('invisible');
    });

    $(window).resize(function() {
        if ($(window).width() < 850 && !$('.navbar-collapse').hasClass('invisible')) {
            $('.navbar-collapse').addClass('invisible');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
nav {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 1.5rem;
}

.navbar-toggle {
    height: 40px;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: rgb(150, 150, 150);
    border-width: 1px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-bottom: -10px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}

.navbar-toggle:hover {
    background: transparent;
    color: rgb(229, 229, 229);
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px rgb(229, 229, 229);
}

.invisible {
    display: none;
}

.navbar-collapse {
    flex-basis: 100%;
}

.navbar-collapse ul {
    display: block;
}

.navbar-collapse li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.08);
    padding: 1rem 0;
}@media screen and (min-width: 850px) {
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: none;
    }

    .navbar-collapse {
        display: block;
        flex-basis: auto;
        margin-top: 10px;
    }

    .navbar-collapse ul {
        display: flex;

    }

    .navbar-collapse li {
        border-bottom: none;
        padding: 0px 8px;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
    <nav>
        <h1 class="site-title">Marco Lapegna</h1>
        <button class="navbar-toggle"><i class="fa-solid fa-bars fa-2xl" style="color: #c0c0c0;"></i></button>
        <div class="navbar-collapse invisible">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">WEB DESIGN</a></li>
                <li><a href="">PEI CORNER</a></li>
                <li><a href="">ABOUT ME</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
 </header>
```